package.json for angular 17
I've done a version up from angular 16 to 17 but it didn't work out. I hope you can help. It's the package.json file now.
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "^17.3.4",
"@angular/cdk": "^17.3.4",
"@angular/common": "^17.3.4",
"@angular/compiler": "^17.3.4",
"@angular/core": "^17.3.4",
"@angular/forms": "^17.3.4",
"@angular/localize": "^17.3.4",
"@angular/platform-browser": "^17.3.4",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.3.4",
"@angular/router": "^17.3.4",
"@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^5.12.1",
"@mingleats/ng-extract-i18n-merge": "1.0.2-SNAPSHOT",
"@ngx-loading-bar/core": "^6.0.2",
"@ngx-loading-bar/http-client": "^6.0.2",
"@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
"@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-buttons": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-charts": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-common": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dateinputs": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dialog": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-dropdowns": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-editor": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-excel-export": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-grid": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-inputs": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-intl": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-l10n": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-label": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-layout": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-listview": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-menu": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-messages": "^1.56.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-notification": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-pager": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-pdf-export": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-popup": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-progressbar": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-toolbar": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-tooltip": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-treelist": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-treeview": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-angular-upload": "^15.5.0",
"@progress/kendo-data-query": "^1.5.5",
"@progress/kendo-drawing": "^1.16.3",
"@progress/kendo-licensing": "^1.3.3",
"@progress/kendo-theme-default": "^6.7.0",
"@progress/kendo-ui": "^2024.1.319",
"@telerik/kendo-draggable": "^2.2.0",
"@types/file-saver": "^2.0.1",
"@types/lodash": "^4.14.157",
"bulma": "^0.8.0",
"file-saver": "^2.0.2",
"hammerjs": "^2.0.0",
"jquery": "^3.7.1",
"localforage": "^1.7.3",
"lodash-es": "^4.17.15",
"moment": "^2.29.4",
"ngx-moment": "^6.0.2",
"ngx-spinner": "^16.0.2",
"rxjs": "^7.5.5",
"tslib": "^2.4.0",
"zone.js": "~0.14.4"

},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-builders/custom-webpack": "^17.0.2",
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.0",
"@angular-eslint/builder": "17.3.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "17.3.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "17.3.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "17.3.0",
"@angular/cli": "^17.3.4",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.3.4",
"@angular/language-service": "^17.3.4",
"@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract": "^5.0.0",
"@biesbjerg/ngx-translate-extract-marker": "1.0.0",
"@fullhuman/postcss-purgecss": "^4.0.3",
"@mingleats/ng-extract-i18n-merge": "1.0.2-SNAPSHOT",
"@types/jasmine": "~3.6.0",
"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
"@types/jquery": "^3.5.29",
"@types/node": "^14.0.14",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^5.62.0",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin-tslint": "^5.62.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "^5.62.0",
"@typescript-eslint/typescript-estree": "^5.62.0",
"autoprefixer": "^10.2.5",
"codelyzer": "^6.0.2",
"eslint": "^8.51.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "^8.10.0",
"eslint-plugin-html": "^7.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-import": "^2.28.1",
"eslint-plugin-jsdoc": "^39.9.1",
"eslint-plugin-prefer-arrow": "^1.2.1",
"eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.4.0",
"husky": "^7.0.0",
"jasmine-core": "~4.2.0",
"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
"karma": "~6.3.2",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
"karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^2.0.0",
"lint-staged": "^11.0.0",
"moment-locales-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.0",
"ng-packagr": "^17.3.0",
"postcss-import": "^16.1.0",
"postcss-loader": "^8.1.1",
"postcss-scss": "^4.0.9",
"prettier": "2.3.2",
"protractor": "~7.0.0",
"resolve-url-loader": "^5.0.0",
"tailwindcss": "^2.0.4",
"ts-node": "~8.10.1",
"tslint": "~6.1.0",
"typescript": "~5.4.5",
"webpack": "^5.41.1"

}
npm run start
error TS2304: Cannot find name 'JQueryStatic'.
240     var jQuery: JQueryStatic;

/node_modules/@progress/kendo-ui/index.d.ts' is not a module

While checking multiple sites, I can't even get the latest version for Kendo. Can't I use the node module without fixing it?

Probably the best thing to do is to remove node_modules folder, and run 'npm install' again. Then try npm run start one more time
